# get Subquery returns more than 1 row error when use auto_increment in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I create two tables sequence and sequence_test,the definitions are follows:

```sql
create table sequence
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment comment 'id'
        primary key
)comment 'sequence' collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table sequence_test
(
    id    bigint unsigned auto_increment comment 'id'
        primary key,
    se_id bigint unsigned not null comment 'trigger'
)
    comment 'test' collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

then I create a MySQL trigger to generate the se_id value when insert row into sequence_test table ,the trigger definition:

```sql
create trigger id_generator
before insert
on sequence_test for each row
begin
    if new.se_id is null then
        insert into sequence value ();
        set new.se_id=(select last_insert_id() from sequence);
    end if;
end;
```

then when I insert table, I get error like [21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row,and why?

Answer (score 1):

I have known the answer, here

```sql
set new.se_id=(select last_insert_id() from sequence);
```

use

```sql
set new.se_id=last_insert_id()
```

last_insert_id() will return the last insert value

Comment: 哥们，不要自己提问自己问答，要不然容易被踩的

Comment: 不是，开始确实不知道因为什么，后来才找到答案